# keeping spaces and formatting when reading/importing into R

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

Yet another question that's probably kind of trivial, but I need to process some CSV data to upload into a software suite that's very particular about formatting. In particular, I need to keep all spaces in variable names and some columns of data untouched (rather than converted into periods, as is R's default).

For something even more annoying, one of the columns of data I mentioned before also has punctuation.

Luckily, none of these variables really come up in my actual code (apart from a column reordering at the very end), so it doesn't matter how they're classified (factors, strings, what have you)

Basically, my data reads

```
TMI Serial Number, AB Version, OrganType, P
0000-07E6-421A-0009, Comm. 003.003.001 2015-05-27 15:51:17 buildmgr, FOOT Thing Doer, 1.22
```

, I'm only doing anything with P (apart from the rest of the variables coming along with the ride when I subset based on P), and I really everything to keep the formatting it has coming in.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output here? I'm unclear on the code you are running and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: If you're trying to read that data into R from a CSV file (as I believe you are), then a simple read.csv([filepath]) gives the output I think you're expecting (a dataframe with four headers, one entry per header). Since you've tagged read.csv, I'm going to assume I'm misunderstanding something here

Comment: I need to get "TMI Serial Number" rather than "TMI.Serial.Number".